# ms-webview src property points to "local-stream:///" not "ms-appdata:///"

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have some code that loads an html file in a `ms-webview` within a Windows 8 store app (winJS) and I'm having an issue checking the URL `src` of the `ms-webview`. Basically, the user is able to navigate within the local html files, but I want to detect when they are back on the "home" screen...

```
var home = "ms-appdata://local/somefile.html";
myWebView.addEventListener("MSWebViewContentLoading", function(e) {
    console.log(myWebView.src); // something like: ms-local-stream://[app_key]/somefile.html
    console.log(e.uri); // same as above

    if (myWebView.src === home) {
        // nope...
    }
});
myWebView.navigate(home);
```

As you can see above, the webview doesn't seem to give me a way to get the URL that I actually navigated to... Thoughts?

And yes, I could inspect the `ms-local-stream` URL path for the file I'm looking for, but surely there's a way to get the URL that was navigate to from the webview??

Comment: I'm no expert on Win8 apps built with JS, but is there a way to simply emit an observable DOM/JS event when your home HTML page loads? Something like jQuery load event? http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Well, I can add a mutation observer to the `ms-webview` and see when the `src` property changes due to navigation, but it still gives me back the `ms-local-stream` url... I'm working on something though, we'll see if it works.

Comment: My point was to simply abandon the URL-sniff and use an event emitted by the "Home" page to process whatever it is you're trying to do. Any particular reason you need the URL?

Comment: The task I have is to do something whenever that particular URL is loaded, regardless of how the user got there. I do not have control over the content in the webview, however, so I can't emit an event from that page.